# Properly fix UseDeclaredVarsMoreThenAssignments inside loops

Tags: powershell

When I have a script that contains the following structure somewhere:

```
$b = $false
(1..10) | ForEach-Object {
    if ($_ -eq 8) { $b = $true }
}
Write-Host $b
```

I will get a [UseDeclaredVarsMoreThanAssignments](https://github.com/PowerShell/PSScriptAnalyzer/blob/development/RuleDocumentation/UseDeclaredVarsMoreThanAssignments.md) warning (in VS Code).

Using either `$script:b` or `$global:b` solves the issue. Using the global scope is a bit overkill since I can't be sure I change any other variables.

But is using `$script:` the proper way of solving this warning or are there other ways to get rid of it?

Comment: I know that your code is a deliberately contrived example, but here, and in general, one thing to do is re-think how your code works.  For example, the following gives the same result, but avoids the warning: `if((1..10) -contains 8) { $b = $true }`.  Also, you can [suppress specific warnings](https://github.com/PowerShell/PSScriptAnalyzer#suppressing-rules).

Comment: @boxdog Yeah, this is just to give an example which triggers the warning. In this case I could just do `$b = (1..10) -contains 8` to get the result.